# How do i sum numbers that come from an answer from a "for in" loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
gjeld = [79, 99, 598, 879, 299, 99, 79, 299, 99, 299, 598, 897]

for n in gjeld:
    if n > 500:
        print(n)
```

the list above is lets say taxes and i needed to find taxes above 500 and print the sum of all numbers that are over 500.
It would print:

```
598
879
598
897
```

in that order, and i need a way to sum up all those numbers together.(Its a school task)

i tried doing:

```
gjeld = [79, 99, 598, 879, 299, 99, 79, 299, 99, 299, 598, 897] 
a=[]

for n in gjeld: 
    if n > 500:
        a.append(n)
        print(n)
```

but it didnt work

Comment: You're not doing anything with `a`. Try `print(sum(a))` after the loop.

Comment: Are you looking for `print(sum(a))`?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a school assignment, I'll assume they don't want you to use the `sum()` built-in function, so let's do the summing by hand:

```
total = 0

for n in gjeld:  # loop over gjeld 
    if n > 500:  # if n is over 500, then
        total = total + n  # compute total + n, and assign back to total

print(total)  # print the total computed after the loop
```

If `sum()` is allowed, then you'd be looking at

```
a = []

for n in gjeld: 
    if n > 500:
        a.append(n)

print(sum(a))
```

If generator expressions or list comprehensions are allowed – and this is the most Pythonic way to write this -

```
print(sum(n for n in gjeld if n > 500))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is a good start, but all you have done so far is put the numbers higher than 500 in a list, so after the loop `a = [598, 879, 598, 897]`. After you finish creating the list, you need to add together everything in the list, which you can do with `sum(a)`

```
for n in gjeld:
    if n > 500:
        a.append(n)
        print(n)

print(sum(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a generator:

```
gjeld = [79, 99, 598, 879, 299, 99, 79, 299, 99, 299, 598, 897]

print(sum(x for x in gjeld if x > 500))
```

This will give you the sum of any/all values in the list greater than 500. It will not print the individual values.

Alternatively:

```
print(sum(filter(lambda x: x > 500, gjeld)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gjeld = [79, 99, 598, 879, 299, 99, 79, 299, 99, 299, 598, 897] 
a=0

for n in gjeld: 
    if n > 500:
        a=a+n
        # print all above 500
        print(n)
# print after sum
print(a)
```